# java text in textfield messing up

Tags: java, jtextfield

**[UPDATE] i fixed the problem. user "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" was right, i changed 3D graphics settings prefer to nvidea driver and problem fixed**

i have problem and can't understand what is matter.
i am creating simple GUI window and putting JTextField object on it.
when i run project and enter text in text field it does not displays properly.

i already tryed to reinstal java, but can't fix problem.

can anyone help me?

here is my GUI window image

[image]

here is my code (no exception thrown, nor error was occured!)

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Form().Run();
    }
}

class Form{
    JFrame form = new JFrame();
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    JTextField txt = new JTextField();

    public Form(){
        form.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        form.setSize(500, 500);
        form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn.setText("caption");
        form.add(btn);

        txt.setColumns(10);
        form.add(txt);
    }

    public void Run(){
        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please, and also the stacktrace if any exception is thrown

Comment: Without code, the cause of your problem is anyone's guess. Please don't make us guess.

Comment: Your computer doesn't use an nVidea graphics video card, does it?

Comment: Is this your actual code? The image has a button which doesnt seem to be in the code

Comment: @Reimeus The button is visible to the left of the visibly-corrupted area. Its caption is "caption".

Comment: my notebook has nVidea graphics video card support

Comment: @hexafraction yes but it wasnt there a few minutes ago :))

Comment: @jao nVidia isn't a question of "support". It's the question of whether it has an actual piece of circuity, called the graphics card, manufactured by a company called nVidia.

Comment: i missed code for JButton at the begining of the post, thought that it was extra code here

Comment: You are still not answering my question, so I am leaving this question. My guess is that you will want to change the settings of your computer's video card, but without more information, I'm going to have to leave it at that.

Comment: my notebook has two video card, one is integrated intel(R) HD  Graphics 4000, second is nVidia GeForce GT 740M, i think my system uses intel(R) graphics by default. so what i have to do (sorry for late comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your "Look and Feel" settings in your GUI-Class, there should be the string "Nimbus". Change it to "Windows" and try it again. The second thing you can try is to set a Border to your JTextfield, probably it works.

The code for changing or to set a Border on your JTextfield:

```
JTextField your_field = new JTextField(10);
your_field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.black));
```

Comment: i already solved this problem. solution is written in bold text! thanks for your response.