# When typing something in JTextField, the text is randomly appearing and disappearing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield

so I wrote a simple game in Java and programmed the gui for it, but I have trouble with a text field, that is used for writing commands. When I hit "run" in Netbeans, the game runs smoothly, but then I start typing the command in the field and with every letter I hit, the parts of the text I already wrote are randomly appearing and disappearing. Like :
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxChL.jpg)

[image]

the first one is before I start typing, the second one should say morning and the third one should say good morning. And everytime I add another character the text changes and some parts appear and some disappear. Why is it doing this?

Comment: without code, we can't guess..

Comment: Possibly a driver issue. Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823367/java-text-in-textfield-messing-up) and a couple of others.

Comment: check your graphic driver[vga]

Comment: So I read your link kiheru and I have the nvidia vga, and yesterday I updated the driver so you really think that's the cause? Otherwise , the effect in the link is the same as mine, so the code is similar too.

Comment: It's my guess. I don't have the issue but I recognized the effect from other questions. So I don't know what settings you need to change, in case that's the cause.

Comment: So I changed the default GPU for Netbeans to the nVidia card and it's working now. Thank you for help :)